# SharePoint Content Editor CSS customization caching

Tags: css, sharepoint, caching, sharepoint-2007

When SharePoint's content editor CSS file (HtmlEditorCustomStyles.css) is customized how can I get the updated css file updated on the client browser?

In testing I've found the updated version is ignored in favor of the browser cached version and I've only been able to get the updated version by deleting the CSS file from the browser cache (or just deleting the cache completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you figure out where the CSS file is being included, you can add a URL parameter to the end of the include. For example if you find the include is:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="[some path]HtmlEditorCustomStyles.css">
```

You can add:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="[some path]HtmlEditorCustomStyles.css?revision=1">
```